Are injectivity and surjectivity sufficient conditions for bijectivity?
I am trying to wrap my head around this:
Bijectivity requires that a functions is both injective and surjective. In a bijective function every element of the domain is mapped uniquely to an element in the codomain. I don't see how this is logically implied by surjectivity and injectivity.
Given for example a function f(x) = x+1, f: R -> N
This function is surjective and injective, but there are elements in R that cannot be mapped to N. Is it then bijective?
I'm new to this platform, so hope I'm asking in the right way, thanks :-)

Your example of course isn't bijective, in fact it isn't even well defined. You've only defined it on a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

In any function, every element of the domain is mapped uniquely to an element of the codomain. Bijectivity is the opposite: every element of the codomain is mapped uniquely from an element of the domain.

This answer assumes that $~\Bbb{N}~$ represents $~\Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}.$

Is the function a bijection?
This is a tricky question.  Normally, before considering whether (for example) a function (or mapping) is a bijection, you have to first specify the domain and the range (i.e. codomain) of the function.
So, as already suggested in the comments:

One viewpoint is that it is required that the domain (and range) be specified before the question of bijectivity can be considered.  Under this protocol, the question of bijectivity can not even be considered, because the domain has not been explicitly specified.
A similar, but moderately different viewpoint is that the domain has been specified as all of $~\Bbb{R},~$ in which case you have a problem.  Such a viewpoint, which is reasonable, leads to the conclusion that the range can not be limited to $~\Bbb{N},~$ because (for example) $~f(1/2) \not\in \Bbb{N}.$  So, you are then forced to conclude that the function's specification is nonsensical.

An alternative viewpoint is that the only rational inference as to the function constructor's intent, is that the domain is limited to those real values of $~x~$ such that $~f(x) \in \Bbb{N}.~$ 
This is a very non-standard viewpoint.  On the other hand, having a function whose specifications are nonsensical is also unusual.  So, it is arguable whether one might reasonably infer that although
the domain is not explicitly specified, it can be inferred from the constraints of

$f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{N}.$

$f(x) = x+1.$

From the bullet point directly above, you know that 
$f(x) \in \Bbb{N} \iff x \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$  So, you might reasonably infer that the intent is that the domain is $~\Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Based on this non-standard viewpoint, the function is a bijection.





Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I'm quite new to this level of math, and what I think I get from your answer, is that I have misunderstood what the codomain is.
I thought you were free to define (in this case, restrict, I guess) the codomain of a function. But what I get from the answers here, is that the codomain of a function is per definition the set that follows strictly from the results of applying the function to all element in the domain. Is that correctly understood this time around?

@user2661923 Whoa, hold on. The codomain is explicitly directly defined. Otherwise, 'surjective' would be meaningless, because every function would be surjective by definition!

@Deusovi +1 : Outstanding rebuttal, which makes perfect sense.  I have therefore deleted my previous comment.  The explanation of my mistake is that my only formal exposure to set theory was somewhat vague references given by my high school math teacher in the late 1960's.  So, I tried to wing it, and you caught me going off the rails.

Ahh, gotcha. What you were referring to is typically called the image of the function; a function is surjective if its image covers its whole codomain. (Hence surjective, meaning "cover", like in "surface" and "surplus".) Annoyingly, "range" can be used both ways - as the codomain or the image, which is probably what led to your confusion!

You specify:

Given for example a function f(x) = x+1, f: R -> N

This is not a function of the appropriate type. For $f$ to be a function, it must associate to each $x$ in the domain some element of the codomain (which we then write $f(x)$).
This doesn't do that. For $x=\frac12$, there is no element of the codomain ($\mathbb{N}$) specified as $f(x)$. So this is not a function at all (or at least, not one of the type you want it to be).
